# Autoload tuareg-mode for .ml4 files

Tags: ocaml, tuareg

What do I need to change in *tuareg.el* to get Emacs to automatically load *tuareg-mode* for .ml4 files?

I can easily change to *tuareg-mode* manually, but it would be nice not to have to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to change `tuareg.el` but your `.emacs`

```
(setq auto-mode-alist
  (cons '("\\.ml[iylp]?$" . tuareg-mode) auto-mode-alist))
```

You must have this line in your `.emacs` so change it with

```
(setq auto-mode-alist
  (cons '("\\.ml[iylp4]?$" . tuareg-mode) auto-mode-alist))
```

Best :-)

Comment: Yes, but that code is not in my .emacs, but in a file in /etc/emacs/site-start.d/. The change there does the the trick, thanks.